# Need help / advice building a habitable body for a book

Tags: physics, hard-science, solar-system

## **Information and Context**

---

I'm working on a story, based 220 or so years in the future in a hard-science universe (where a quantum jump drive has been invented). I was wondering if anyone could give me some information and advice.

This is also my first time doing any project like this.

I plugged some information into [this](http://www.transhuman.talktalk.net/iw/Geosync.htm) calculator.
Plugged in values:

- Day length: 120 (I want it to be really long)
- Mass: 0.4 (I want less gravity)
- Radius: 0.7 ( ^^ )

Output values:

- Density: 1.16618

  - Minimum Density: 2 g/cm3
  - Typical Density: 5.2 g/cm3
  - Maximum Density: 11.1 g/cm3
  - Actual Density: 6.437 g/cm3
- Radius: 8920 km
- Surface Area: 249.9 million km2
- Roche Limit: 1200 km
- Surface Gravity: 0.82 Gs
- To Orbit Velocity: 5.99 km/s

  - Thrust Time to Orbit at 3 Gs: 4.9 minutes
- Escape Velocity: 8.5 km/s

If that's too much information, or not enough, please say so.

For plot reasons, It would be nice if the days and nights were *really* long.
Also, I'd like the planet to be a bit darker / cooler than earth, but still be bright enough to easily see (for humans) on the surface.

### **Questions**

1. What could the planet's sun / orbits look like?
2. How long is viable for a day / night cycle with that sun / orbital system?

If you have any general tips, or ideas, or links to share, please do! Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Thanks to all those who gave me advice as I am very new to this!!

Comment: Wow this is a lot of stuff! Just to warn you, you might get some 'too broad' close votes, since it's usually encouraged not to ask more than one question per post. I recommend maybe asking some of these separately, and also looking around on the site to see if there's anything useful. Best of luck!

Comment: Please, one question per, ummm, question.

Comment: Yes this is rather a lot to ask in one go - can you restrict it to 1 or at most 2-3 closely interrelated questions

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, BallisticPorpoise, you have dived in at the deep end. What makes your question(s) too broad is that many of them would be substantial essays each. Basically this is asking a lot. Let me recommend Stephen L Gillet's *Worldbuilding* as the go-to text. For publication details, see here: https://www.bookdepository.com/World-Building-Stephen-L-Gillett/9781582971346

Comment: "A quantum jump drive" doesn't sound as particularly belonging to hard-science to me...

Comment: Interesting question, welcome to WorldBuilding. I'd recommend taking a look at our already existing questions, you might find some of them interesting. For example to use the search box in the upper right: [\[planets\] long day is:q](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bplanets%5d%20long%20day%20is%3aq) will search for all questions tagged [tag:planets] that contain the words "long" and "day" yielding stuff like [Realistic sky of an Earth-like moon orbiting a gas giant (length of day and size of celestial bodies)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/70158/28789)

Comment: Note that this was just a random example to get you started. The [tour] and [help] provide more information about how to use the site and if you got any questions about using the sites features [Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/) would be the place to ask. Have fun on the site and good luck with your project!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Worldbuilding. Your question is a bit odd to me. As for point 1... eh, why would it be any **different** compared to orbits as we know them? The tautological answer is "As orbits normally look". Point 2, you ask: "How long is viable for a day / night cycle with that sun / orbital system?". I cannot make any sense of that at all. The grammar of the question is all mangled. Can you please rephrase that?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the Day/ Night cycle,  There is no real physics based reason you can't just say the day is however long you want it to be.

In terms of what an orbit looks like, taking a bit of a look at what goes on in Mars should demonstrate for you that what you want is supported by Hard Science fairly easily.  A somewhat eccentric orbit will give you seasonal variations to your hearts content

Here is a picture of Mars Orbit:
[image]

This came from a page that describes quite a bit about what goes on in Mars that is similar to what you are trying to do: https://www.universetoday.com/14717/how-long-is-a-day-on-mars/